# Why do I receive a Type mismatch error using If Not Range.Value Like in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to delete all rows where the value in Column "A" doesn't match the following field formats (1) 7 digit number, (2) Lastname, Firstname, (3) Date ... or the following values (4) INPATIENT (5) OUTPATIENT.

Line 9 keeps throwing a "Type Mismatch" error.  Any ideas?

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()
Dim RowToTest As Long

Call setVariables   '***sets wsName variable

    'Code to delete unneeded rows based on cell value in Column "A"
    For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(RowToTest, 1)
                If Not .Value Like "???????" Or "*[,]*" Or "*?[/]*?[/]*??" _
                  Or "?????[:]*" Then
                    If Not .Value = "INPATIENT" Or "OUTPATIENT" Then
                        Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
                    End If
                End If
        End With
    Next RowToTest
End Sub
```

Comment: the error pops up cus of the `...Or "*[,]*" Or...`

Comment: It's odd that you calculate the last cell in column A on some worksheet somewhere but within the loop that uses that number very specifically define not only the worksheet but also the workbook to use that number upon.

Comment: you need to do the `like` for each part... try it this way: `If Not (.Value Like "???????" Or .Value Like "*[,]*" Or .Value Like "*?[/]*?[/]*??" Or .Value Like "?????[:]*") Then`

Comment: Where is your Date test? Also deleting row by row will be very slow for larger data sets. Testing for "???????" is any character - not numeric specific.

Comment: `"*?[/]*?[/]*??"` is his date :)

Comment: @DirkReichel that matches many more strings than a date.

Comment: @brettdj as long as it works the way he want it I wont question it :P

Answer (score 3):

your function should look like this:

```
Public Sub DeleteRows()
  Dim RowToTest As Long

  Call setVariables   '***sets wsName variable

  'Code to delete unneeded rows based on cell value in Column "A"
  For RowToTest = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Cells(RowToTest, 1)
      If Not (.Value Like "???????" Or .Value Like "*[,]*" Or .Value Like "*?[/]*?[/]*??" Or _
                .Value Like "?????[:]*" Or .Value = "INPATIENT" Or .Value = "OUTPATIENT") Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(wsName).Rows(RowToTest).Delete
      End If
    End With
  Next RowToTest
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
If Not .Value Like "???????" And _
     Not .Value Like "*[,]*" And _
       Not .Value Like "*?[/]*?[/]*??" And _
         Not .Value Like "?????[:]*" And _
       .Value <> "INPATIENT" And _
     .Value <> "OUTPATIENT" Then
    Rows(RowToTest).EntireRow.Delete
End If
```